# How do I dynamically create a Video object in AS2 and add it to a MovieClip?

Tags: flash, video, actionscript-2

I need to dynamically create a Video object in ActionScript 2 and add it to a movie clip.  In AS3 I just do this:

```
var videoViewComp:UIComponent; // created elsewhere    

videoView = new Video();
videoView.width = 400;
videoView.height = 400;
this.videoViewComp.addChild(videoView);
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to accomplish this in AS2.  Video isn't a child of MovieClip, so attachMovie() doesn't seem to be getting me anything.  I don't see any equivalent to AS3's UIComponent.addChild() method either.

Is there any way to dynamically create a Video object in AS2 that actually shows up on the stage?

---

I potentially need multiple videos at a time though.  Is it possible to duplicate that video object?

I think I have another solution working.  It's not optimal, but it fits with some of the things I have to do for other components so it's not too out of place in the project.  Once I get it figured out I'll post what I did here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got something working.

First, I created a new Library symbol and called it "VideoWrapper".  I then added a single Video object to that with an ID of "video".

Now, any time I need to dynamically add a Video to my state I can use MovieClip.attachMovie() to add a new copy of the Video object.

To make things easier I wrote a VideoWrapper class that exposes basic UI element handling (setPosition(), setSize(), etc).  So when dealing with the Video in regular UI layout code I just use those methods so it looks just like all my other UI elements.  When dealing with the video I just access the "video" member of the class.

My actual implementation is a bit more complicated, but that's the basics of how I got things working.  I have a test app that's playing 2 videos, one from the local camera and one streaming from FMS, and it's working great.

Answer (score 1):

To send you the ends of a line which is a tag, I use HTML Symbol Entities from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_symbols.asp)

An example, taken from a project would be as follows:

```
< asset path="library\video.swf" />
```

The line above shows that there is a directory called library which contains the file `video.swf`

Besides, there is the file video.xml in the directory library. That file contains the lines

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" >
<movie version="7">    
    <frame>
        <library>
            <clip id="VideoDisplay">
                <frame>
                    <video id="VideoSurface" width="160" height="120" />
                    <place id="VideoSurface" name="video" />
                </frame>
            </clip>
        </library>
    </frame>
</movie>
```

Long ago my son Alex downloaded the code of VideoDisplay class and the directory library from Internet

I have iproved the code of the class VideoDisplay.

by writting 2 members

```
 public function pos():Number
{
    return ns.time;
}

     public function close():Void
{
    return ns.close();
}
```

The program I have created 
is 
more than an explorer and presenter of `.flv` files

It also
is an explorer and presenter of the chosen fragments of each `.flv` file

Now the code of VideoDisplay class is:

```
class util.VideoDisplay
{
    //{ PUBLIC MEMBERS


    /**
    * Create a new video display surface
    */

    function VideoDisplay(targetURI:String, parent:MovieClip, name:String, depth:Number, initObj)

    {
        display = parent.attachMovie("VideoDisplay", name, depth, initObj);

        // create video stream
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(targetURI);
        ns = new NetStream(nc);

        // attach the video stream to the video object
        display.video.attachVideo(ns);
    }

    /**
    * Video surface dimensions
    */
    function setSize(width:Number, heigth:Number):Void
    {
        display.video._width = width;
        display.video._height = heigth;
    }
    /**
    * Video clip position
    */
    function setLocation(x:Number, y:Number):Void
    {
        display._x = x;
        display._y = y;
    }

    /**
    * Start streaming
    * @param    url FLV file
    * @param    bufferTime  Buffer size (optional) 
    */
    public function play(url:String, bufferTime:Number):Void
    {
        if (bufferTime != undefined) ns.setBufferTime(bufferTime);
        ns.play(url);
    }
    /**
    * Pause streaming
    */
    public function pause():Void
    {
        ns.pause();
    }
    /**
    * Seek position in video
    */
    public function seek(offset:Number):Void
    {
        ns.seek(offset);
    }   

    /**
    * Get position in video
    */

     public function pos():Number
    {
        return ns.time;
    }

         public function close():Void
    {
        return ns.close();
    }

    //}

    //{ PRIVATE MEMBERS 

    private var display:MovieClip;
    private var nc:NetConnection;
    private var ns:NetStream;

    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a single instance of the Video object, leave it invisible (i.e., `videoview.visible = false`), and load the clip when you need it, displaying it at the appropriate time. You can also use `swapDepth()` if it becomes necessary.

Video handling in AS2 is not the best thing ever. Rest assured you'll run into a lot of little problems (looping without gaps, etc).

Answer (score 0):

your approach is what i usually do  because other option is to include the UIcomponent mediaDisplay into library and then attach that component using attachMovie but i found mediaDisplay i little buggy so i prefer to use the primitive video instance .

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the code below will be very useful for you:

```
import UTIL.MEDIA.MEDIAInstances

class Main

{
    static function main() {

        var MEDIAInstancesInstance :MEDIAInstances  = new MEDIAInstances (); 

        _root.Video_Display.play ("IsothermalCompression.flv", 0);

        _root.VideoDisplayMC.onPress = function() { 

        _root.Video_Display.seek (0);        

        } // _root.displayMC.onPress = function() {

    } // static function main() 

} // class Main 

// 

import UTIL.MEDIA.VideoDisplay  

class UTIL.MEDIA.MEDIAInstances             

    {  

    function MEDIAInstances() 

    {

    //                                            depth  
    _root.createEmptyMovieClip ("VideoDisplayMC", 500);   
    //
    var Video_Display:VideoDisplay 
    = 
    new VideoDisplay(_root.VideoDisplayMC, "Video_Display", 1); 

    Video_Display.setLocation(400, 0); Video_Display.setSize (320, 240);      
    //    
    _root.Video_Display = Video_Display;  _root.VideoDisplayMC._alpha = 75;      

    } // MEDIAInstances()

} // class UTIL.MEDIA.MEDIAInstances

//

class UTIL.MEDIA.VideoDisplay

{
    private var display:MovieClip, nc:NetConnection, ns:NetStream;

    function VideoDisplay(parent:MovieClip, name:String, depth:Number)

    {
        display = parent.attachMovie("VideoDisplay", name, depth);

        nc = new NetConnection(); nc.connect(null); ns = new NetStream(nc);

        display.video.attachVideo(ns);
    }
    function setSize(width:Number, heigth:Number):Void

    { display.video._width = width; display.video._height = heigth;}

    function setLocation(x:Number, y:Number):Void { display._x = x; display._y = y;}

    public function play(url:String, bufferTime:Number):Void
    {
        if (bufferTime != undefined) ns.setBufferTime(bufferTime); ns.play(url);
    }
    //
    public function pause():Void { ns.pause();}
    //
    public function seek(offset:Number):Void { ns.seek(offset); }

} // UTIL.MEDIA.VideoDisplay
```

Comment: So this code - unless I am mistaken, attaches an existing movieclip (from where?) named "VideoDisplay" with a video dropped onto its stage? Or have I missed something here? Is there a way to do this totally dynamically, or does it all come back to dragging stuff onto a stage?